# Is there an easy way to show that this function satisfies Cauchy Riemann equations at $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let

$$ f(z) = \left\{ \begin{align}
&e^{-\frac{1}{z^4}}  &\hspace{1mm} \mbox{if} \hspace{1mm} z \neq 0 \\ 
&0  &\hspace{1mm} \mbox{if} \hspace{1mm} z = 0 \\ 
\end{align} \right. $$

*I want to show that this equation satisfies, CR equations at $z=0$*

Let $z=x+iy$ where $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. Then 
$$\frac{1}{z}=\frac{x-iy}{x^2+y^2}.$$

I get the following expression.

$$e^{-\frac{x^4+y^4-6x^2y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^4}}\left(\cos\left(\frac{4xy^3-4x^3y}{(x^2+y^2)^4} \right)-i \sin\left(\frac{4xy^3-4x^3y}{(x^2+y^2)^4} \right)\right)$$

I have shown that this function satisfies CR equation, but is very tedious.

Is there a more elegant and beautiful way? Or Is this the only way possible.

Comment: Just an idea: have you tried polar coordinates?

Comment: No. Not yet. My notes does not mention anything like that. Let me Google it.

Comment: Polar coordinates CR equations assume $r\ne 0$. I am not sure if they are applicable here.

Comment: Look equations 18 and 19 http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cauchy-RiemannEquations.html

Answer (score 2):

For $z = x \in \Bbb R$, $x \ne 0$ is $f(z) = e^{-1/x^4}$ purely real,
so that
$$
 \begin{aligned}
 u(x, 0) &= e^{-1/x^4} \\ v(x, 0) &= 0 
 \end{aligned}
$$
and therefore
$$
 \begin{aligned}
 u_x(0, 0) &= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{u(x, 0)-u(0, 0)}{x - 0}
 = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{-1/x^4}}{x} 
 = \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{t}{e^{t^4}} = 0 \\
 v_x(0, 0) &= 0 \, .
 \end{aligned}
$$
In a similar way you can show that
$$
 u_y(0, 0) = v_y(0, 0)  = 0 \, .
$$
All partial derivatives are zero at $z=0$, so that the Cauchy-Riemann
equations are satisfied at that point.

Comment: +1 wow,nice one